# Opencart weird and unknowable table prefix

Tags: php, mysqli, opencart

I wanted to practice mysql queries, so I took the `mysqli.php` from Opencart system/library /db folder, and put it into a test folder. This database class worked for all of my other database queries, but when I create a php file and make the queries to my Opencart database tables, Php always reports
`Notice: Error: Table 'test.[TheTableName]' doesn't exist`

Query is simplest one line, I have no idea and I can't find from where this test. prefix has added to my queried table.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: define('DB_PREFIX', 'test.'); in config.php ?

Comment: Could you post the `mysqli_connect` statement & your database name? maybe there is a difference in both.